# Registering Table Cells found nil while unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a tableview within a container view so I can animate it, unlike a regular UITableViewController.

In storyboard created a UIViewController with a UIView as a "containerView". Inside the containerView is a tableView. IDK why it keeps giving me nil.

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.register(SearchViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchResult")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchResult", for: indexPath) as! SearchViewCell
        cell.addressLabel.text = "Hello"
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = "There"
        return cell
    }   
}
```

SearchViewCell

```
class SearchViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- This register

```
tableView.register(SearchViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchResult")
```

is valid only with programmatically created custom cells  ( clearly ones with no outlets )

2- For prototype cells ( when you create the cell inside the table in layout ) , then you don't need a register

3- If you created the cell layout in xib , then there is another way of register

```
 tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SearchViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
```

Comment: I tried using Nib, but I keep getting an error. "Could not load NIB in bundle. Would using nib work with something I created using Main.storyboard?

Comment: For the identity inspector in cell, I set it to SearchResultCell. For attribute inspector inspector, I set the identifier to SearchResult. When changing the forCellReuseIdentifier, why don't I use SearchResult? Usually we use the same identifier?

Comment: Make sure xib is `SearchViewCell.xib` for above code to work

Comment: Thanks your answer worked! But can you explain why we use different identifiers? I usually use the same when coding programmatically and it works. Im confuse why this time it didnt

Comment: `forCellReuseIdentifier` can be anything put for `nibName` it should same name as you created